# Mudando data a ser mostrada no datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Estou fazendo um calendário com `datepicker`, e preciso que esse calendário mostre apenas segundas, e o mais importante, que mostre um mês depois da data atual, ou seja, terá que mostrar a partir do dia 27/05 só as segundas-feiras.

Já consegui fazer que ele mostre as segundas, agora minha dúvida é, como fazer para ele mostrar a partir do próximo mês?

Código JS:

```
$(function() {
          $( "#data-inicio" ).datepicker({
             beforeShowDay: function(date){ 
              return [date.getDay() == 1,""]} 
          });
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode acrescentar [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) para definir a data mínima de seleção, o [`beforeShowDay`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) para habilitar os dias disponíveis (você já conseguiu, mas só para exemplificar tudo):

```
$(function() {
    // Data atual, já considerado a partir do próximo mês
    var today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate() + 30);
    // Verifica se esta data cai em uma segunda-feira
    // Se não cair, precisa obter a próxima segunda depois deste dia
    if (today.getDay() != 1) {
        // Primeiro dia do próximo mês para calcular quantos dias faltam para o mês atual acabar
        var nextMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 1);
        // Total de dias para acabar o mês. A subtração é feita em milessegundos, então as multiplicações são realizadas para obter este valor em dias
        var days = Math.floor((nextMonth - today) / (1000*60*60*24))
        // Se faltam menos de 7 dias para virar o mês, quer dizer que não existirá outra segunda-feira neste, então a data mínima do datepicker será no próximo mês.
        if (days < 7)
            today = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + days);
    }

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() == 1, ""] },
        minDate: today
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvz46yf7/8/)**

Answer (score 3):

tenta configurar o mindate dele... ai vc seta o minDate com o mes+1.
https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate